# tableau - automatically update password for all datasource in workbench

Tags: tableau-api

We are using tableau to connect to VDP (Data Virtualization tool from TIBCO) and then read the data from VDP and create dashboards. As part this exercise we have multiple data source connections. Our intention is to use a proid (in production) for those data source connections. Now proid password gets expire in every 90 days. So my question is whether there is an option that the passwords for all the data source connections change automatically after every 90 days. I mean the password can be kept saved in a secure file and tableau will read that file and update the password automatically for all the data source connections after every 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to embed passwords for data sources published to Tableau server. The passwords are encrypted at rest, and then you can update the connection when needed. This is easier to manage in production if you publish the data sources separately from the workbooks that reference them

Comment: thanks! But the embedded password would still have to be manually changed every N days, correct? The benefit of using the embedded password is that it could potentially update multiple dashboards at once, if multiple dashboards use the embedded creds, right?

Comment: If you publish a data source separately, and then have multiple workbooks connect to the published dashboard, then you can maintain the embedded password in one place (in the published data source). If instead, you embed your data source in your workbooks, each will have to be updated when the password changes. If your organization purchased the data management add-on (recommended) then you can use virtual connections to have even more control over shared connections

Comment: Correction to last comment, should say “connect to the published *data source*”